# read multiple times a text file for duplicates in java

Tags: java

I am writing a program that should create a file and then generate a unique id , read the file and if any duplicates are present in it generate a new id and repeat the check.

As of now I am able to create the id and write into the file. But my issue is I' m not able to check if any duplicates are present in the file.

Here is the code which I tried:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String a[]) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("text.txt");
    file.createNewFile();
    FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
    filewriter.write("\r\n");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(filewriter);
    String alphanumeric = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    Random random = new Random();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // randomInteger = random.nextInt();
        sb.append(alphanumeric.charAt(random.nextInt(alphanumeric.length())));
    }
    System.out.println("\n Random Alphanumeric in Java: " + sb.toString());
    // reading data from file
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String string;
        while((string = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(string.equals(sb.toString())) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    // randomInteger = random.nextInt();
                    sb.append(alphanumeric.charAt(random.nextInt(alphanumeric.length())));
                }
                bw.write((sb.toString()));
                System.out.println("new value :" + sb.toString());
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("existing value :" +sb.toString());
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        System.out.println("File not found!!");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Put everything into a `List`, put everything from the `List` into a `Set`. Compare the size of both.

Comment: Why not check for duplicates befor writing into file through map/set?

Comment: You might also want to have a look at [UUIDs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)

Comment: Could u please help me with the code.
As i have been tried in many way.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong here
1:

```
if(string.equals(sb.toString())) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                // randomInteger = random.nextInt();
                sb.append(alphanumeric.charAt(random.nextInt(alphanumeric.length())));
            }
            bw.write((sb.toString()));
            System.out.println("new value :" + sb.toString());
        }
```

This adds to the existing id as `sb` is never reset to empty.

2:
What you are doing now is:

```
generate id

for each line L do
  if L equals id
     append to ID
     write id
  else
     some output
end for
```

What you should be doing:

```
while not inserted
  generate id
  for each line L do
    if L equals id
       found = true
       break // exit for each
  end for
  if found
      continue //restart while loop
  insert into file // we only get here if it was not found
  inserted = true
end while
```

For better performance first read all the IDs into a list and use it to check for existing ids instead of reading the file every time.

Comment: Care to give a reason why you unaccepted the answer?